# Android - Thread issue. A static worker thread and two different AsyncTasks

Tags: android, multithreading

I have the following CameraPreview class that has this setPreviewCallback implemented which will run a static thread.

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) { 
        ...
        AThread thread = new AThread(data, ....);
        thread.start();
        Preview.this.invalidate();
        ....
    }
});
```

And the static thread with two AsyncTask (TaskOne and TaskTwo).

```
private static final class AThread extends Thread {
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (....) {
            Looper.prepare();
            new TaskOne().execute(.....);
            ...
            ...
            if (.............) {
                // Log.d(.....) // message is printed
                new TaskTwo().execute(.....); // doInBackground not executed.. why?
                // Log.d(.....) // message is NOT printed.. why??
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error. TaskOne will be executed. However, TaskTwo will not be executed even the condition is true. I did a Log.d and it did went in however, TaskTwo is never executed. I think there is a thread/queue problem. Can anyone help me solve this?

EDIT:
I read post like there can be only 1 AsyncTask on a a thread. I think TaskTwo is not added because TaskOne has not completed yet. Am I right??

Comment: new TaskOne().execute(.....) just start execution of TaskOne, its not waiting until it's end ... so if "if" statment depends on changes made in TaskOne it will be never true ... anyway there is no need for more than one AsyncTask especially when you're are using new Thread ...

Comment: the if statement does not depend on TaskOne. I need a new AsyncTask as they both are doing a separate task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Two Different `AsyncTask` in one `Activity`. I would insist not to call the `AsyncTask` from any thread but execute it from the `Main` `UI` `thread` itself. If you have the issue that while calling another `AsyncTask` the previous might be running, you can put a flag in the `postExecute()` of the running `AsyncTask` to get its status that it is completed. Another is you can try using [`getStatus()`](http://getStatus) to get the current status of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @Poptani The AsyncTasks are not called from the UI thread. It is called in the worker thread as it depends on data/information in the worker thread. What should be the correct way? It is part of this [code](http://code.google.com/p/android-motion-detection/source/browse/trunk/src/com/jwetherell/motion_detection/MotionDetectionActivity.java) but I am adding another AsyncTask to perform my own task, which relies on the data in that worker thread.

Comment: AsyncTasks `doingInBackground()` itself is executed in the worker thread(bacground) then why you need to call asynctask from a thread.

Comment: @Poptani Due to OOP, I had written that AsyncTask function previously to perform a task (which is called by the UI thread). Since I need the same function over here to perform the (same) task, I simply made a call to initialise that AsyncTask object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your AsyncTask:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  myTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
}
else {
  myTask.execute();
}
```

It seems that you need parallel tasks.
It is clarified here:
[(link)](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html).